# RegularExpressionAttribute Equivalent for SymbolUtilityServices.ValidateSymbolName

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

In AutoCAD there is a utility for determining if a string is valid for a symbol name, i.e. a Block or Layer name for instance. This utility is:

```
try
{
    // Validate the provided symbol table name
    SymbolUtilityServices.ValidateSymbolName(s, false);
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s + " is a valid name.");
}
catch
{
    // An exception has been thrown, indicating that
    //    the name is invalid
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s + " is an invalid name.");
}
```

where "s" is the string you are testing.

See [How to check if a given string is a valid name for an item in a symbol table?](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/how-to-check-if-a-given-string-is-a-valid-name-for-an-item-in-a-symbol-table.html)

Since this tool throws an exception if the name is out of compliance, I would much rather use a Regex Attribute to do the same, something like:

```
[RegularExpressionAttribute(@"^[a-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special characters not allowed")]
```

But here lies my problem I am not well versed with Regex. So what would the expression be to disallow these characters:

\<>/?":;*|,=`

(spaces allowed)

[image: Unsupported characters in block name]

Your thoughts and help are appreciated.
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
[RegularExpressionAttribute(@"^[a-zA-Z \d_-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Certain special characters not allowed")]
```

Does seem to do the trick, I put this together, but I feel like it doesn't explicitly disallow the characters, instead, it only allows certain characters.

If there is a more concise answer I will accept it.